# Calling modules and passing back data in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, module, ironpython

I am running into another issue where when i call a module containing a port scanner that returns an array of open ports, instead getting anything back the application closes.  I have tried using `import GetPorts` as well as `from GetPorts import Ports` and even using `execfile` to just execute it but no matter how its called, the application closes.  Visual Studio is not giving me any feedback on why it closes beyond just a Return 1 (0x1) in the output frame.  Below is the code I have used to call the GetPorts module as well as the module in case there is an error there.

Current Main App:

```
import wpf
import sqlite3
from GetPorts import Ports

    #declare array to receive open ports
    OpenPorts = []

    self.TB_Top_Results.Text = self.TB_Top_Results.Text + "Before Port Scan" 
    #does not appear when run despite coming before what crashes the app

    #call module to scan for and return open ports
    OpenPorts = Ports.func(LocalIP)

    #display open ports in results text box
    self.TB_Top_Results.Text = OpenPorts
```

importing GetPorts method:

```
import GetPorts
...
...
...
OpenPorts = GetPorts.Ports.func(LocalIP)
```

execfile method, I hardcoded the IP into the GetPorts module:

```
import GetPorts
...
...
...
OpenPorts = execfile(GetPorts.py)
```

GetPorts:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class Ports:
    def func(IPadd):

        #Create connection
        remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(IPadd)        

        # Check what time the scan started
        t1 = datetime.now()

        #Create Array to store open ports
        OpenPorts = []

        #Loop through port numbers
        try:
            for port in range(5000,5100):  
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
                if result == 0:
                    OpenPorts.append(port)
                sock.close()


        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "You pressed Ctrl+C"
            sys.exit()

        except socket.gaierror:
            print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
            sys.exit()

        except socket.error:
            print "Couldn't connect to server"
            sys.exit()

        return OpenPorts
```

Comment: In you exec_file, it wouldnt do anything, because you are not calling `func`. As for the others, is it printing an empty array? Or does the LocalIP have a port open in that range? you can always try a debugging print in your try statement to print the port if that a port in that range is actually open

Comment: So I have tried putting in a line before it even calls the function to print into the results textbox and it never executes...so long as the function is being called.  I tried putting them inside of the function to see if it was processing, they never execute either.  As far as I can tell, its terminating the app cleanly as Visual Studio has no errors and the debugger finds nothing.

Comment: Lets get away from VS code for a second. There could be many reasons why it is not working or showing an error in VSCode. Can you update your question with the output of running your script in a terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately not, its an Ironpython WPF application.  If I try it says it cannot find the XAML file.